# Create a boolean feature to check if two columns are the same

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe `DF1` that has three features (columns) a,b,c, all of StringType. I want to create a new dataframe `DF2` from `DF1` that has two columns:

1. The column a
2. A new column d with 1 if `b=c` otherwise 0

Input example:

```
a b c  
A B B  
B C A  
D D D
```

Wanted output

```
a d  
A 1  
B 0  
D 1
```

Comment: Please use This `df1.withColumn("d",col("b") === col("c"))`

Comment: If features are meant as columns. a, b, c are three columns. how come you say four? please clarify and review your question with clear examples.

Answer (score 6):

The part missing is `drop` for the other two columns.

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("d", col("b") === col("c")).drop("b").drop("c")
df2.show
```

This gives us

```
+---+-----+
|  a|    d|
+---+-----+
|  A| true|
|  B|false|
|  D| true|
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use This `val df2=df1.withColumn("d",col("b") === col("c"))`

Here WithColumn will add new columns in df2.

Comment: withColumn will add a new column in old DF. OP is asking for only two features ( columns)

Answer (score 1):

For me, as I was using pyspark, below commands worked

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("d", col("b") == col("c")).select(col("a"), col("d"))
df2.display()
```